# Send and Receive data to and from server using sockets in java

Tags: java, sockets

I have a client which connects to a Server via socket and sends some data, server reads the data and returns response.

Below is my method in to send and receive data from server

```
public static String  sendAndReceiveDataToNode(String address, int port, String data) throws ConnectionFailedException {
        Socket me = null;
        DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
        DataInputStream inputStream = null;
        String responseData = null;
        try {
            me = new Socket(address, port);
            outputStream = new DataOutputStream(me.getOutputStream());
            outputStream.write(data.getBytes());
            outputStream.flush();
            LOGGER.info("Data written from client");
            inputStream = new DataInputStream(me.getInputStream());
            responseData = convertStreamToString(inputStream); // here i call inputStream.readLine()
            return responseData;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            closeOutputStream(outputStream);
            closeInputStream(inputStream);
            closeSocket(me);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

If i use `outputStream.flush()` then my server blocks at inputStream.readLine() and data i write never reaches server. If i use me.shutdownOutput() then data reaches server but client do not blocks at inputStream.readLine() to receive data from server and reads empty string, Although client blocks for readLine when i use outputStream.flush().

In server i have below code

```
public void run() {
    DataInputStream inputStream = null;
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    while (running) {
        try {
            this.clientConnection = receptionistSocket.accept();
            inputStream = new DataInputStream(clientConnection.getInputStream());
            String requestData = Util.convertStreamToString(inputStream); //Here i call inputStrea.readLine()
            //Do Some time consuming operation
            String data = createResponse(requestData) ;
            outputStream = new DataOutputStream(clientConnection.getOutputStream());
            outputStream.write(data.getBytes());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error occurred while accepting client connection");
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error occurred while accepting client connection");
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        finally {
            Util.closeInputStream(inputStream);
            Util.closeOutputStream(outputStream);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Below is missing code

```
public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw e;
            }
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
```

I have gone through many tutorials but none of them is solving this problem.

Where Am i mistaking?

Comment: We cannot help if we cannot see all the relevant code.  Please post all the missing code. Also, why would you call `readLine()` on a `DataInputStream`?  That is not how `DataInputStream` is intended to be used.

Comment: I just added the missing function. I am using BufferReader and hence readLine. For more code i have my repository open in github. The server class is https://github.com/kgcorner/Aquila/blob/master/balancer/src/main/java/com/kgaurav/balancer/Receptionist.java and and Client code is in https://github.com/kgcorner/Aquila/blob/master/balancer/src/test/java/com/kgaurav/balancer/UtilTest.java